# Moving textblock at runtime with code

Tags: c#, xaml

How to make a textblock moving up and down with code at runtime? like when i click a button, it starts moving. i also want to keep it moving(loop) up and down. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you using WPF or windows forms?

Comment: _One_ possible way would be to animate the `RenderTransform` of the `TextBlock` object. As stated, your question is far too broad. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried so far, along with a precise explanation of what the code does, and how that's different from what you want it to do.